# Will I get electrocuted holding the container inner surface while lightning strike?

Tags: lightning

I am building a house made of containers. The container is placed on 1 feet high concrete and no parts touching the ground but the distribution box has a wire to the grounding copper.

I read about Faraday's Cage but just wanted to know more about the risk.

Well, on the event of lightning strike, will I get electrocuted if I touch the inner surface of the container? Because most people standing inside the cage doesn't touch the cage by hand. They stand in the middle.

Thank you

Comment: It depends. _**A Faraday cage is made to form an alternate path for electricity to travel from source to ground without travelling through the object inside the cage.**_ So if the Cage is complete then there is no problem in touching the inner surface. That is why people wear cloths out of metallic mesh which also acts as a Faraday cage. But remember the cage should be complete.

Comment: For clarification, I'm guessing from the context that the containers are metal?

Comment: @RedAct, yup the container is made from corten steel. 
I don't place any insulation inside, so basically the inner part of it are totally exposing the metal part.

Comment: The answer to that is not in physics textbooks but in the building code. You may not get electrocuted, but your house might still cause a fire, if it is installed on foundations that don't have sufficient grounding. Get a local electrician who knows the code for steel structures to check if for you. If I had this problem and I lived in an area with frequent thunderstorms, would probably look at the code and then double the required grounding.

Comment: Sure @CuriousOne I will refer to electrician for this matter.
Just being skeptical and wanted to double confirm the matter :)

Comment: The building codes are usually based on some first hand engineering experience in the matter, which physicists don't have (unless they happen to work in civil engineering...). We aren't running around investigating  building problems. Whatever we tell you about these things comes from bloody amateurs who can't help themselves talking about matters they have zero experience with. :-)

Comment: I was sitting in my container and got either a direct hit or very very close. Arced my power board for just a split second with an instant burnt smell and sounded like a .308 going off next to your ear. Did no damage to my electrical equipment or me thankfully. I have a large glass sliding door in the side and foam insulation and it seems to have acted as a faraday cage. The container itself isn't grounded however for fire proofing purposes I piled layers of soil up all around the outside to about 150mm from the bottom to prevent hot embers getting underneath to the timber floor. I should add

Comment: This thread just totally informed me... and killed my dream of building a container home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Faraday cage is made to form an alternate path for electricity to
>   travel from source to ground without travelling through the object
>   inside the cage.

So if the Cage is complete then there is no problem in touching the inner surface. That is why people wear cloths out of metallic mesh which also acts as a Faraday cage (check for **EMF** shield clothing). But remember the cage should be complete, which means the circuit of the cage should be complete.

[image: David embarks doing his stunt]

Comment: Hi Hari, what do u mean by complete cage?
The container indeed has few opening (glass windows and doors)

Comment: Which means the circuit of the cage should be complete. Else the current will chose the other shortest possible path to complete the circuit

Comment: In my scenario, the container is placed on 1 feet high concrete.
no parts touching the ground. But the distribution box has a wire to the grounding copper, can it be considered as completed cage?

Comment: Yes it is complete. Also add what you just said to the question to make others understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fast transient that a lightning strike presents, there might be resistive and inductive voltage drops in different parts of the container. So don't touch two different parts of the container during lightning strike. If you are actually building this, please also note that you the entire container will be a lightning attractor, so during a thunderstorm, it is very likely that your container actually will be struck. I would not want to be the first person to stand with both feets on that container floor during a lightning strike.

Comment: Why would the container structure be a "lightning attractor?"

Comment: Because it is a higher point (spatially) at ground potential compared to the ground which it stands on. This means the electrical insulation between the thunder cloud and the ground is weakened at the container.

Comment: I have a vinyl flooring installed on the container floor.
And most of the time I will not really touching the wall. 

I used to get electrocuted when I help holding 2 separate metal bars on my right and left hand (rectangular frame and Im in the middle) and happened that the electric running through my body. 

Maybe the path is shorter and possibly cause that to happened?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that it is not necessarily safe to touch your container, as some other answers have suggested. Regarding the 2 separate metal bars, you don't provide enough information to know what caused the electric shock. Were the two metal bars connected with a conductor? What was the source of the electricity?

Comment: The "shorter path" that you mention, probably comes from the "current will choose the shortest path" statement. There are two things to note here: the word "shortest" is not meant as the spatially shortest path, it is meant as the path of least resistance for the current. Secondly, the statement is commonly misinterpreted as "if you have two paths of different resistance for the current, all current will take the least resistive path." This is incorrect, the current will distribute between the two paths, in proportion to the resistivity. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_divider